# Differce between builtin type objects and custom objects in dynamic adding attributes

Tags: python

Say I have a custom class `Box`:

```
class Box(object):
    pass
```

I try to add an attribute `prop`:

```
box = Box()
box.prop = 1     # works
print(box.prop)  # 1
```

But if I do the same thing on an `int` object:

```
num = 1
num.prop = 1
```

Result

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'prop'
```

Questions:

1. How to explain behavioural difference between `num` and `box`?
2. How can I make a custom class (Box2) behave like an `int`, i.e. to raise `AttributeError` after `box2 = Box2(); box2.prop = 1`?

Comment: Check out `__slots__`.

Comment: When you type `num = 1`, `type(num)` is `int`, `int` doens't have `prop` attribute. You can use `__slots__` and have only wanted attributes in it.

Comment: @MarounMaroun So doesn't `box` or `Box` have `prop` attribute. But why `box.prop = 1` is allowed?

Comment: For more info, see http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/8/16/the-python-i-would-like-to-see/

Comment: @MichaelBrennan: slots he describes are not about `__slots__`.

Comment: related: [Python `__slots__`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/472000/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian You're right. I knew that, but got confused, again.

Comment: Here couple of links that'll help you https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__ , https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html .